# Preg allowing Blank records

Tags: php, regex

I have the below code for matching an email address using regular expression rules.

It works well, but I've recently noticed that it seems to match a "Blank" email address.

```
if (preg_match("/.* <.*@.*\..*>/i",$this->to,$matches)) {
  $this->email_to = preg_replace("/.*<(.*)>.*/","$1",$this->to);
} else {
  $this->email_to = $this->to;
}
```

My understanding of the preg_match is:-

1. Looks for any character, except a line break
2. < anycharacter@anything.anything >
3. Case-insensitive?

Following those rules, I can't quite work out why it matches a blank / no email address if someone can give some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do if `$this->to` is empty?

Comment: Just skip/discard the record if empty, Toto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No needs for `preg_match`  + `preg_replace`.

```
if (empty($this->to)) {
    $this->email_to = 'Is empty'; # assign what you want
} elseif (preg_match("/<(.+?@.+?\..+?)>/", $this->to, $matches)) {
    $this->email_to = $matches[1];
} else {
    $this->email_to = $this->to;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it behaves like that but an easy solution is to ask if the string is blank

```
if (preg_match("/.* <.*@.*\..*>/i",$this->to,$matches)) {
  if ($matches != ""){
      $this->email_to = preg_replace("/.*<(.*)>.*/","$1",$this->to);
      } else { $this->email_to = $this->to; }
} else {
  $this->email_to = $this->to;
}
```